# How to remap keys in Vim VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim, vscodevim

I'm remapping keys in settings.json (VS Code) like that:

```
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before":["<S-j>"],
      "commands": [
        ":m-2",
      ]
    },
    {
      "before":["<S-k>"],
      "commands": [
        ":m+",
      ]
    } 
  ]
```

So when I try to type Shift-k, I see `:m+` in Vim command line but it's not performed. I think I need to use `<CR>` somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: In **VSCode**, there is no need to add `<CR>`, for example in the *Quick Example* of the extension doc, just use the `"commands": [":nohl"]` there.

Comment: @Rocco Yes I know, but as I mentioned, it doesn’t work,  I see :nohl in Vim command line but it's not performed.

Comment: This comment is just an addition, the specific reason I wrote in the answer: the *Ex command* `move` of Vim is not implemented in VSCode currently, If you want to achieve the same function of your code, you can do as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, most of the *Ex commands* of **Vim** is not implemented in **VSCode**, you need to map the keys to the internal implementation and commands of **VSCode**. For example, if you want to **move line up/down**, you can add mappings for *Normal mode* and *Visual mode* like this:

```
{
    "vim.visualModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": [ "K" ],
            "commands": [ "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction" ]
        },
        {
            "before": [ "J" ],
            "commands": [ "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction" ]
        }
    ],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": [ "K" ],
            "commands": [ "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction" ]
        },
        {
            "before": [ "J" ],
            "commands": [ "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

IMHO, `J` itself is a useful command, so I mapped these two commands to `_` and `-`.

Similarly, if you want to **copy line up/down**, you can map the `editor.action.copyLinesUpAction` / `editor.action.copyLinesDownAction` command. To get other commands, you can open the **Keyboard Shortcuts** list, then right click and copy command ID. For more to see [VSCode Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) and [Built-in Commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands).